# NodeJS - Socket.io - Users on a specific page

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm currently working on a project using Node.js and Socket.io and for the sockets, I use Redis as I subscribe to multiple channels.

The application signs a user in (Through an API -- Using OAuth) and what I basically want is to show is a list of people that are signed in (their avatar) but I'm struggling to work out how I would do this using the Redis server. I have tried to do this on connect but this does not work.

Can anyone recommend a way that I can do this effectively? Basically show the avatar of the user (or username) that are currently signed into the system.. It should be real-time so that's why I'm going down the socket direction.